# Django GenereicForeignKey v/s custom manual fields performance/optimization

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm, generic-foreign-key

I'm trying to build a typical social networking site. there are two types of objects mainly.

1. photo
2. status

a user can like photo and status.  (Note that these two are mutually exclusive)
means, We have two table (1) for Image only and other for status only.

now when a user likes an object(it could be a photo or status) how should I store that info.

I want to design a efficient SQL schema for this.
Currently I'm using Genericforeignkey(GFK)

```
class LikedObject(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

but yesterday I thought if I can do this without using GFK efficiently?

```
class LikedObject(models.Model):

    OBJECT_TYPE = (
        ('status', 'Status'),
        ('image', 'Image/Photo'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="liked_objects")
    obj_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    obj_type = models.CharField(max_length=63, choices=OBJECT_TYPE)
```

the only difference I can understand is that I have to make two queries if I want to get all liked_status of a particular user

```
status_ids = LikedObject.objects.filter(user=user_obj, obj_type='status').values_list('object_id', flat=True)
status_objs = Status.objects.filter(id__in=status_ids)
```

Am I correct? so What would be the best approach in terms of easy querying/inserting or performance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically implementing your own Generic Object, only you limit your ContentType to your hard coded OBJECT_TYPE.

If you are only going to access the database as in your example (get all status objects liked by user x), or a couple specific queries, then your own implementation can be a little faster, of course. But obviously, if later you have to add more objects, or do other things, you may find yourself implementing your whole full generic solution. And like they say, why reinvent the wheel.

If you want better performance, and really only have those two Models to worry about, you may just want to have two different Like tables (StatusLike and ImageLike) and use inheritance to share functionality.

```
class LikedObject(models.Model):
   common_field = ...

   class Meta:
      abstract = True

   def some_share_function():
      ...

class StatusLikeObject(LikedObject):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="status_liked_objects")
   status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name="liked_objects")

class ImageLikeObject(LikedObject):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="image_liked_objects")
   image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name="liked_objects")
```

Basically, either you have a lot of Models to worry about, and then you probably want to use the more Django generic object implementation, or you only have two models, and why even bother with a half generic solution. Just use two tables.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would check if your data objects `Status` and `Photo` may have many common data fields, e.g. `Status.user` and `Photo.user`, `Status.title` and `Photo.title`, `Status.pub_date` and `Photo.pub_date`, `Status.text` and `Photo.caption`, etc.

Could you combine them into an `Item` object maybe? That `Item` would have a `Item.type` field, either "photo" or "status"? Then you would only have a single table and a single object type a user can "like". Much simpler at basically no cost.

Edit:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Item(models.Model):
    data_type = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=((1, 'Status'), (2, 'Photo')), default=1)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    ...etc...

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="liked_objects")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Comment: could you please provide some code, I'm unable to visualize your thoughts.